# How to install Ubuntu on empty disk space along side Win7?

Tags: installation, 12.10

I have a computer that is partitioned between Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. Long story short, I wanted to make a fresh install of 12.10, so I copied all of my personal data from 12.04 over to my Win7 partition, the deleted the partition that had 12.04 on it:

[image]

What I want to do now is install Ubuntu 12.10 on all of the empty disk space. Thus I open the installer, and I am presented with the option to install over the entire HDD, or "Something Else". I click on something else, and I am presented with this window:

[image]

How do I use this window to install Ubuntu 12.10 over the rest of the unallocated/free space on my HDD? I have no idea how to do it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your desired partition setup, just click on the free space and click the "+" to add a swap partition of whatever size you want, and then click the "+" again to create a / partition (probably with the default ext4 file system, unless you want something specific from another file system) filling the rest of the drive (or split your / and /home into separate partitions if you'd like to preserve your data should you need to reload Ubuntu).

After it's installed, you'll be presented with a Grub menu to choose to boot Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: This seems like the right way, but it's still a little unclear as to how to do it. I really want to be sure of what I am doing, I do not what to lose any data.

Comment: Perhaps this will give you more detail: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: ...and *always* have a backup before doing anything like this - nothing is guaranteed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In gparted there, you can right click a partition or use the options in the partition button on the menu bar to select resize partition on one of your partitions, allowing you to allocate unallocated space for Ubuntu to install on.

Once you are done, make sure to select Apply Changes.